# error: RPC failed; result=6, HTTP code = 0

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

On my staging server running Ubuntu, I execute `git pull`, I kept getting :

> error: RPC failed; result=6, HTTP code = 0
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I've increase Git’s HTTP buffer by setting.

`git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`

and do `git pull` again, and still got the same error.

How do I fix this so I can perform my `git pull` again ?

Answer (score 0):

It can mean that either the host can't be resolved (you can check this by pinging it, for example) or that curl isn't installed (`apt-get install curl` or `yum install curl`)